# Brunch IO configuration issue

Tags: web-deployment, brunch

I am using the following base for a Backbone Marionette application: [link](https://github.com/vip32/brunch-with-marionette)

When I run `$ brunch watch --server` it is working fine on `localhost:3333` . However, it is not working from my iPhone browser (on same WiFi) via `192.168.x.x:3000` . Another project using `gulp` and Browser Sync is showing up on the iPhone browser using same strategy. 
Now, I have two questions:
1. Is there a way to test a site being served by basic brunch dev server on a mobile device ? [Solved now! Please refer to the comment below.]

**2. This seems to be an even more serious issue, if I take the `public` folder (where the built output is supposed to go) and put it inside an Apache document root, the site is not working and just shows a blank page with no console errors. There doesn't seem to be any file access permissions issue etc.
What is the right way to deploy this app now ?**

Here is my brunch `config.coffee`:

```
exports.config =


# See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.



files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
    'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
    'javascripts/vendor.js': /^(bower_components|vendor)/

stylesheets:
  joinTo:
    'stylesheets/app.css': /^(?!test)/
  order:
    after: ['vendor/styles/helpers.css']

templates:
  joinTo: 'javascripts/app.js'
```

Comment: I figured it out. So, the following addition was needed to `config.coffee`:

      server:
        port: 9000
        hostname: '0.0.0.0'

The default being `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` does not let it through. However, am still not sure about the issue with the contents of output `public` directory not working in Apache. Please let me know how I should approach deployment in this case.

Comment: I don't see how Brunch is to be responsible here. It just builds your js and copies index.html. Most likely, it's something in the apache configuration or something... Do you see the scripts loading in the Resources tab of the Inspector? Are you sure there are no error (it could be that your Console tab is filtering for a certain kind of logs — warnings for example, and disregarding other logs)